# connect to mysql.. host changed in error?

Tags: mysql

Is connecting with one IP but an error occurs with a complete strange host/ip??

```
new mysqli('88.198.55.xxx', 'root', 'pass', 'db');
```

This returns

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'static.226.106.46.78.clients.your-server.de' (using password: YES)
```

I really don't get it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message that you are seeing was generated by the MySQL server, and reports that the connection attempt from `'root'@'static.226.106.46.78.clients.your-server.de'` was denied.  The host given in that message will be the hostname of the connecting client (i.e. the server on which PHP is running).

The reason for the access denial could either be because the `'root'` user is not permitted to connect from that host (using password authentication), or that the password is incorrect.